# How to get a logger on my own class name using Play2/scala?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.1

In Play 2, I used this code to get a logger:

```
public class LoggerHelper {
    public static Logger getLogger() {
        final Throwable t = new Throwable();
        t.fillInStackTrace();
        final String fullClassName = t.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        return Logger.getLogger(fullClassName);
    }
}

public class MyController {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerHelper.getLogger();
}
```

In Play 2, the code sample I found looked something for getting a logger looked something like this:

```
class MyController {
  private val log = Logger(classOf[MyController])
  ...
}
```

How can I generify it not to include the class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misreading your question, but it looks like all you need is

```
class MyController {
  private val log = Logger(this.getClass)
  ...
}
```

or have I misunderstood your needs?

Comment: It might, yeah. I'm a scala noob, didn't realize it was so simple - in Java the above doesn't work because Controllers use static methods which don't have `this`. BTW, I also saw someone just do `play.api.Logger.info("...")` in Play - what is recommended, this or what you suggested?

Comment: with org.slf4j  this  worked for me: 

private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[_])